# Can we input array in curl function and follow the result for each element?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, function, curl

My question is simple, but for me, it is creating so many confusions in my mind. I want to know that can we input an array to curl function ?

**please note that 'I AM NOT POSTING DATA' (FOR POSTING DATA , I KNOW, ARRAY IS USED)**

To make my question more clear, let me tell you the code ..

```
function mycurl($url){
$ch = curl_init(); // create a new cURL resource
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$data = curl_exec($ch); // grab URL and pass it to the browser
//echo $data; //ncomment for debugging
curl_close($ch); 
return $data;

}
```

and array  i am going to use is

```
myArray 
0 => string 'http://www.abc.com/a
1 => string 'http://www.abc.com/b
2 => string 'http://www.abc.com/c
3 => string 'http://www.abc.com/d
```

to use the array, I am using `foreach` loop the code is given below

```
foreach ($myArray as $temp){
    $heading= mycurl($temp);
    echo $heading;
    }
```

the purpose of the code is

> go to each url of array using curl function
>
> extract required
>   data from the url
>
> process the next element of array and extract
>   data and so on

Can anybody guide me that How can i use array elements in curl function?
How can i get my objective? If `foreach` loop is not the correct methodology here, then what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your doing looks good, except, you shouldn't initialize the curl handler for every iteration, just initialize it once, then change the $url value for every iteration, would look something like:

```
function mycurl($ch, $url) {

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    return curl_exec($ch); 
}

$ch = curl_init(); // create a new cURL resource

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $header = mycurl($ch, $url);
    var_dump($header);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: thaks for the reply, i have done like it, but it is taking too much time, and randomly displays an error that "30second time out error", i know the reason that there are many elements of array , so taking time, is there any way to improve the performance and speed?

Comment: How far into the array stack does it reach before it throws the error? Try setting `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` to 0, and see if that helps.

Comment: i changed the time out in php config to 90 seconds..and it almost worked. if my network connection is okay, it works, if the connection is slow at the moment, it randomly gives error, and setting connect time out option fully resolve this problem.

Comment: Ahhh cool. Ya we had to set it to 0 for a project where we would remain logged in for a few hours pulling huge datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right. However you can use [`curl_multi_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) (see examples) to launch all requests at once, classical curl can do only one request at the time.

Little more effective way to do your code would be:

```
$ch = curl_init(); // create a new cURL resource
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

foreach( $myArray as $url){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $data = curl_exec( $ch);
    echo $data;
}

curl_close( $ch);
```

Or with correct object design:

```
class MyClass {
    protected $ch = null;

    public function __construct( ){
        $this->ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        curl_close( $this->ch);
    }

    public function getData( $url){
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        return curl_exec( $this->ch);
    }
}

$extractor = new MyClass();
foreach( $myArray as $url){
    $data = $extractor->getData( $url);
    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: thanks dear, thanks for the answer, i got read the example and what i understand is that, i should use curl multi exec if i have to run multiple instances at the same time, but i want to run one instance (one element of array), do some scrapping work, and then run the next instance, so the code remains same?